# How can I make xcodebuild use cache?

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild

When I run Xcode and constantly build to the simulator, it can be very fast (few second). I think it uses cache and only builds files that have been modified. How can xcodebuild do the same? In other words, if I were to use xcodebuild, how can I make it use the cache or faster?